# Lookup with multiple criteria and preserve formatting

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I have a MASTER sheet with Item Code (Col. B), Description (Col. C), Unit (Col. D), Location1_Rate (Col. E), Location2_Rate (Col. F), Location3_Rate (Col. G), Location4_Rate (Col. H), Location5_Rate (Col. I), Location6_Rate (Col. J), Location7_Rate (Col. K)

I work with an OUTPUT sheet configured as follows
Location selection (Location_1 to Location_7) as dropdown menu: A16
Item Code: Col. D (to be manually entered)
Description: Col. F
Quantity: Col. G
Unit: Col. H
Rate: Col. I
Amount: Col. J

Whenever I enter the Item code (Col. D) in OUTPUT sheet, the description of the item as well as the rate for the corresponding location should appear automatically in corresponding cell of Col.F and Col. I respectively. The first Item Code starts with the cell D20.

 
 
Since, my objective was to preserve the formatting in the OUTPUT sheet, I used VBA code for the description field. I am successful in the VBA code for returning the rate of a single location (Location1_Rate). But, I am unable to modify the code for getting the rate of a different location(based on  the location in Cell A16). Please peruse the code and suggest.

**Note**: *I have multiple MASTER sheets for looking up the Item code and hence the VBA I mentioned takes into account lookup across multiple sheets. But, the two-dimensional lookup as described above, is only needed for the MASTER Sheet1.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Fnd As Range
Dim NotFnd As Boolean
Dim Ws As Worksheet
NotFnd = False
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Target.Column = 4 Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each Ws In Worksheets
If Not Ws.Name = "Output" Then
Set Fnd = Ws.Columns(2).Find(Target.Value, , , xlWhole, , , False, , False)
If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
NotFnd = True
Fnd.Offset(, 1).Copy Target.Offset(, 2)
Exit For
End If
End If
Next Ws
If Not NotFnd Then MsgBox Target.Value & "not found"
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve formatting you should apply formatting on the target like this:

```
With Target.Offset(, 2)
      .Font.Size = 12
      .Font.Bold = True
     whatever
```

Unfortunately format painter is not available from VBA, so if you don't know the format (or want to keep your app flexible) then you need to copy the relevant settings from the source cell, like

```
With Target.Offset(, 2)
      .Font.Size = Fnd.Offset(0, 1).Font.Size
      .Font.Bold = Fnd.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold
     whatever
```

There are a hell a lot of properties for formatting, good luck for finding the relevant ones.

EDIT: Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Fnd As Range
Dim item_row As Long

If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Target.Column = 4 Then Exit Sub

Set Fnd = Sheets("MASTER").Range("B:B").Find(Target.Value, , , xlWhole, , , False, , False) ' item code
If Fnd Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Item not found"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Fnd.Offset(, 1).Copy Target.Offset(, 2) ' desc
    item_row = Fnd.Row  ' row of item
    Set Fnd = Sheets("MASTER").Range("E1:K1").Find(Cells("A16").Value, , , xlWhole, , , False, , False) ' loc name
    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Location not found"
    Else
        Sheets("MASTER").Cells(item_row, Fnd.Column).Copy Target.Offset(0, 5)
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Notes: 1. I would replace hardcoded range and sheetname references with variables to make the sub a bit more flexible 
2. I would develop the sub to support more than 1 cell changes with a something like this:

```
for each c in target
      if c.column = 4 then debug.print c.value
next c
```

Comment: I think I misled you with the title of the post...   
The formatting problem is only relevant to field “Description” which I am able to solve with this code. The primary objective is to match the Location rates (Location1_Rate to Location7_Rate) lookup with different locations based on the text in A16.  
Suppose, in the OUTPUT Sheet, if I change the location in the dropdown menu of A16 to Location_2, the rate adopted should be of Location2_Rate from the MASTER sheet. So, the problem is as good as a lookup with multiple criteria.

Comment: OK. So your objective is to fill in description and loc. rate next to item code when a field in column D fires the sub. You have one MASTER table with all item codes and loc. rates.